# A set S contains a transformation for an independent element, then will S be countable?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $$S=\{\,T\colon \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3 :T\text{ is a linear transformation with }T(1,0,1)=(1,2,3), T(1,2,3)=(1,0,1)\,\}.$$ Then $S$ is
a). A singleton set
b). A finite set containing more than one element.
c). A countable infinte set.
d). An uncountable set

Here dimension of transformation is 3 and only 2 basis vectors are given, which implies that we can define the 3rd independent vector in as many ways as we want. But how does it conclude the given question. I think the answer should be option b) cause of the fact that $T\colon\Bbb R^3\longrightarrow\Bbb R^3$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $v\in\Bbb R^3$ be a vector that turns $(1,0,0), (1,2,3),v$ into a base of $\Bbb R^3$.
Then for any $w\in\Bbb R^3$ (this time  it is the $\Bbb R^3$ on the right), we find a $T\in S$ that sends $v\mapsto w$. As there are uncountably many elements in $\Bbb R^3$, this shows that $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: What if the question said, S={T:$R^3$→$R^3$:T is a linear transformation with T(1,0,0)=(1,2,3),T(0,1,0)=(1,0,1)}. now here v∈$R^3$  are standard ordered basis. Will the answer change?